# How to create opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf and include /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf

Tags: google-compute-engine, bitnami

Please guys help out, am using google compute engine for the first time and using bitnami. I have successfully spin up a server, and connected with ssh but am stock here https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/nodejs/#how-to-create-a-custom-nodejs-application
Can anyone help me explain how:

1.- Create and edit the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf file and add the line below to it:

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

2.- Create and edit the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf file and add the content below to it. This is the main configuration file for your application, so modify it further depending on your application's requirements.

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

> NOTE: 3000 is the default port for the Express server. If you have
>   customized your application to use a different port, change it here as
>   well.

3.- Once you have created the files and directories above, add the following line to the end of the main Apache configuration file at /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf, as shown below:

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Bitnami guide](https://docs.bitnami.com/virtual-machine/components/nodejs/#how-to-create-a-custom-nodejs-application) shared by you, you should follow the following steps (I added more detailed information):

**1.- Create directories**

For that, you should run the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs
```

**2.- Create two files**

For that, you can run the following commands:

```
touch /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf
touch /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf
```

**3.- Add content to the first file**

You can edit the file using any text editor, for example `nano`

```
nano /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf
```

The above command opens the text editor, you should copy/paste or write the following line:

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

Close the editor using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>(you will be prompted to save your file if you have not)

**4.- Add content to the second file**

You can edit the file using any text editor, for example `nano`

```
nano /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf
```

The above command opens the text editor, you should copy/paste or write the following line:

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Close the editor using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>(you will be prompted to save your file if you have not)

**5.- Edit Apache config file**

Once you have created the files and directories above, add the following line to the end of the main Apache configuration file. Open the file (again using `nano`):

```
nano /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf
```

The above command opens the text editor, you should copy/paste or write the following line:

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

Close the editor using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>(you will be prompted to save your file if you have not)

**6.- Restart apache**

For that execute

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

**7.- Start the Express server**

```
cd /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs
./bin/www
```

Alternatively, use the following command to start the server and keep it running even after your server session ends. Replace FILE with the correct filename for your application.

```
forever start FILE.js
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, great explaination.. Understand better now

Comment: can't I use something like npm start?